# Polynomials: Computing p(α+β) from p(α) and p(β)

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, computational-complexity

Somehow I doubt there are useful methods, but maybe I have a blind spot. Assume with have a complex polynomial p with degree n and complex numbers α and β.

And we know p(α) and p(β), is there a quick way to compute p(α+β)? Or are there some particular polynomials p where there is such a method.

**Edit:**
Doing something with the coefficients is allowed. We need to produce p(α), p(β) and p(α+β) at the same time. Everything that is faster than evaluating the polynomial 3-times is quicker.

Comment: What is known about $p$? Only the values $p(\alpha)$ and $p(\beta)$ and that $\deg p=n$? Or do you have coefficients of $p$?

Comment: Define *quick*.

Comment: The answer I posted (and deleted) was offpoint. Srry, I misunderstood parts of your question.

Comment: You need an exact value for $p(a+b)$ right? Or an approximation is good enough?

Comment: I dunno about approximations, do you have some epsilon parameter?